# cannot visit minio server dashboard from ubuntu

Tags: nginx, minio

i am working on nginx and minio on the ubuntu.

the minio server is started from

`'nohup /usr/local/bin/minio server /data/tenant1 --address :9001   >  /opt/logs/minio.log 2>&1 &#'`,

and it is working.

then I started the nginx and configure the nginx server with the following configuration.

```
nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
server {
        listen 9000;
        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:9001;
        }
}
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

from the opening ports, it is clear to see the minio is running on port 9001

```
minio      9349            root   12u  IPv6 35833021      0t0  TCP *:9001 (LISTEN)
nginx     12416        www-data    8u  IPv4 36153228      0t0  TCP *:9000 (LISTEN)
```

At last, the gateway is inactive from the output of `ufw status`. and my server security group also allows 9000.

[image]

however when I tried to visit the minio server dashboard from   http://IP:9000/minio   , it is not working,

any problem with my configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MinIO console dashboard listens on a separate port - you need to specify this with the option `--console-address :10000` - if you do not specify this, a random port is chosen for you and it will be displayed in MinIO's logs in your `/opt/log/minio.log` file. The `9001` port in your setup is for the S3 storage API only.